# Azure AAD Role for Octopus Webapp deployments

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

I'm using Octopus Deploy to deploy an Azure WebApp, using Service Principal as the authentication mechanism.  Following online instructions, I was able to obtain all the id's and a key, and I created permissions in AAD for the app with a Reader role.

Octopus can successfully retrieve a list of webapps from Azure for the account, but when I deploy I get the following:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: Retrieving publishing credentials failed with HTTP
>   status 403 - Forbidden

I'm guessing that the Reader role is not authorized for deployments - which would be the most appropriate role?  Or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Service Principal will need the Contributor role in order to deploy on Azure.

If you take a look at the example PowerShell script we provide in [our Azure Service Principal Account guide](https://octopus.com/docs/guides/azure-deployments/creating-an-azure-account/creating-an-azure-service-principal-account), you'll see that we assign "Contributor" for the role definition argument.

ie.

`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Contributor -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId`

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you think about Walter's recommendation for using Website Contributor?  Would that limit some of Octopus Deploy's powers?

Answer (score 1):

If you only use the Service Principal to deploy web app, you could give it `Website Contributor` role.

> **Website Contributor**   Can manage websites, but not the web plans to
>   which they are connected

Actions that Website Contributor could access please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles#website-contributor).

If you want the service principal to create app service plan, you also need give it `Web Plan Contributor` role.

`Owner` and `Contributor` can manage everything, if you need to fine-tune permissions, I suggest you select `Website Contributor` role. More information please refer to this link:[Built-in roles for Azure role-based access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-built-in-roles).

Please refer to this [link:Assign application to role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Comment: @Savage It depends on your need. If you only deploy your web app, `Website Contributor` is enough. Also, you could give your service principal `Contributor` and `Owner` role.

Comment: @Savage Does it work for you? Please let me know if you need more future help.

Comment: I'll go with `Contributor` because I don't want weird and wonderful issues down the line, and I regard Octopus Deploy as a trustworthy platform. Since I changed to `Contributor` I'm no longer having issues.